# Handling parameter values containing % character in a rewrite rule in apache

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use following RewriteRule syntax in apache and IBM HTTP servers:

```
RewriteRule ^/target$ www.something.com/content?param1=value1&paramN=valueN [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

If a value contains % character, it does not work.
I tried dropping NE flag, no luck.
I tried encoding the % character itself as %25, no luck.
When the rewritten URL shows up on the browser, the % character is missing.
Can someone help with the correct RewriteRule syntax with an example?
Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing the **%** character with a backslash **\** solved the problem.

```
This syntax corrupts the value of parameter p1 by dropping the % character:
RewriteRule ^/target$ www.something.com/content?p1=abx%xyc [R=301,L,NC,NE]

Prefixing % with a backslash preserves the value of parameter p1:
RewriteRule ^/target$ www.something.com/content?p1=abx\%xyc [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

The % character causes the next two characters to be treated as the hex value of an ASCII character. This substitution alters the value of the parameter in the destination URL. Using the \ prefix prevents this substitution.